# LWC Jest: is the subscription part code executed in jest function?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-jest

When I read the sample code in lwc-recipes, it gives me a feeling that in side Promise().resolve().then() in jest method, the subscription of the published message should be received. However, our code looks something like below:

In lwc js:

```
  connectedCallback() {
    this.subscription = subscribe(
      this.messageContext,
      UpdateAccountsAndGoals,
      (message) => {
      //it seems to me this part is not executed during test
      }
```

In jest test:

```
const messageContextWireAdapter = registerTestWireAdapter(MessageContext);
  it("test update accounts and goals secenario", () => {
    getBalances.mockResolvedValue(APEX_FACCOUNTS_SUCCESS);

    const element = createElement('c-account-balances', {
        is: accountBalances
    });
    document.body.appendChild(element);

    const payload = {
      update: true
    };
    publish(messageContextWireAdapter, UpdateAccountsAndGoals, payload);

    return Promise.resolve().then(() => {
        const balanceEle = element.shadowRoot.querySelector('article');
        expect(balanceEle).not.toBeNull();
    });
  });
```

It seems to me that even if I executed the shadowRoot and query Selector part inside Promise.resolve().then() the subscription is still not done yet.

Is there a method similar to test.stopTest() to force that happen?

**---------Edit---------**

I wrote a small proof of concept lwc js file and test file to demonstrate the issue according to the request.

So here is the complete lwc js file:

```
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import { publish, subscribe, MessageContext } from "lightning/messageService";
import UpdateAccountsGoalsTimed from "@salesforce/messageChannel/FinancialAccountGoalsTimedUpdate__c";

export default class SamplePubSub extends LightningElement {
    @wire(MessageContext)
  messageContext;
  subscription = null;
  triggerUpdate;

    connectedCallback() {
      this.subscription = subscribe(
        this.messageContext,
        UpdateAccountsGoalsTimed,
        (message) => {
          if (message.update) {
            this.triggerUpdate = true;
            this.update();
          }
        }
      );
    }

  update() {
    console.log('test');
  }
}
```

And the complete jest test file:

```
import samplePubSub from "c/samplePubSub";
import { createElement } from "lwc";
import { publish, subscribe, MessageContext } from "lightning/messageService";
import {
    registerLdsTestWireAdapter,
    registerTestWireAdapter
} from '@salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest';
import UpdateAccountsGoalsTimed from "@salesforce/messageChannel/FinancialAccountGoalsTimedUpdate__c";

const messageContextWireAdapter = registerTestWireAdapter(MessageContext);

describe("c-samplePubSub", () => {
  //clean the dom and mocks in between test runs
  afterEach(() => {
    while (document.body.firstChild) {
      document.body.removeChild(document.body.firstChild);
    }
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });

  it("test pub sub", () => {
    const element = createElement('c-samplePubSub', {
        is: samplePubSub
    });
    document.body.appendChild(element);
    
    const payload = {
      update: true
    };
    publish(messageContextWireAdapter, UpdateAccountsGoalsTimed, payload);

    return Promise.resolve().then(() => {
      expect(subscribe).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });
});
```

When I run the coverage on this test, it shows that Line 16-25 is not covered which means the resolve part is not executed.

Comment: Can you add a full code where I can repro the test execution? The resolve should have happened

Comment: Hi @MohithShrivastava sorry I can't post the whole set of code. I posted another example of code which is pretty end to end and the comment explains what is not covered in that scenario. Do you mind to take a look?

Comment: it should be MRP code so I can at least replicate! Could be simple example! I will try with what you have in the question!

Comment: @MohithShrivastava I have written a small proof of concept code in the edit area which includes the whole js and jest file, which can demonstrate my issue

Comment: Excellent  will take a peak once I have a chance!

Comment: I have responded! Let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The callback function in your code is not getting called because the standard stubs for lightning messaging service that ship with the `sfdx-lwc-jest` for the project do not implement it.

Since the project is open source you can easily take a peek at the stub implementation [here](https://github.com/salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest/blob/master/src/lightning-stubs/messageService/messageService.js). Notice clearly how the `subscribe` function is stubbed

```
export const subscribe = jest.fn();
```

What we want to do is write our own stub so that we can pass in the callback. Something like below

```
// LMS stub implementation that lets you test a single message handler on a 
single channel
var _messageChannel = null;
var _messageHandler = null;

export const subscribe = jest.fn(
(messageContext, messageChannel, messageHandler) => {
    _messageChannel = messageChannel;
    _messageHandler = messageHandler;
 }
);
```

Create your own custom stub implementation using the [moduleNameMapper](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#modulenamemapper-objectstring-string--arraystring) config of jest

**Steps**

1. Create folders in the force-app with the following paths `/tests/jest-mocks/lightning`(You create tests, jest-mocks, and `lightning` folders in the same hierarchy as I have listed in the path)
2. Create a file named `messageService.js` within the `lightning` folder in step one with the code file [here](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/blob/master/force-app/test/jest-mocks/lightning/messageService.js).
3. Create a `jest.config.js` in your project root with the below configuration

   ```
   const { jestConfig } = require('@salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest/config');
   module.exports = {
    ...jestConfig,
    moduleNameMapper: {
    '^lightning/messageService$':
        '<rootDir>/force-app/tests/jest-mocks/lightning/messageService'
      }
   };
   ```

Rerun the test with the new config and you should see those uncovered lines covered.